# Extra authentication step for OAuth2/OIDC client authorisations from multiple auth servers

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I've currently set up a Spring Cloud Gateway Reverse Proxy with the intention of:

a) Handling Authentication of multiple OAuth/OIDC providers, including obtaining a Token

b) Look up the details from the provider locally, ensuring that the OAuth user x Oauth provider combination are authorised

c) If authorised look up the Grants/Permissions, and forward the request to SCG, with a JWT containing details of the authorised principal.

d) If not authorised display a page displaying pertinent details from the OAuth2 Auth, and explain that they are not authorised.

I have achieved most steps, but I am having trouble incorporating step c) into Spring Security Webflux

What I want to do is take the OAuth2AuthenticationToken obtained from the Authentication exchange, perform the lookup in step, and return a 
bespoke Prinicipal based on results.

This would then be used via code to either trigger the SCG behaviour, or display the page.

spring-boot.version>2.1.6.RELEASE
spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2

My problem is I don't know the best way of doing this.

1. Use some hook in the OAuth2 client to perform the extra auth steps. I may need to return an OAuth2Principal in this case
2. Add an extra security filter into the chain after the authentication.
   This would replace the OAuth2Principal with my own prncipal. I'm not sure whether it is legal to replace a Principal after it has been authenticated, possibly removing the authentication status
3. Writing a custom AuthN Provider that would proxy to the OAuth client, and once competed run it's own logic before signalling that it is authenticated. This seems a complicated approach, and I'm not sure what classes I would use for this.

I've read the Spring Security documentation, and understand the general architecture of Spring Security, but cannot work out the best way of solving this.

This is my spring security filter logic

```java
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    @Profile("oauth")
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return addAuthZ(http)
            .oauth2Login()
            .and().build();
    }

    private ServerHttpSecurity addAuthZ(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated().and();
    }
}
```

And here is the config, I am using sample OAuth2 providers  Google and Facebook and a custom OAuth2 provider provided using CAS

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: SET_ME
            client-secret: SET_ME
          facebook:
            client-id: SET_ME
            client-secret: SET_ME
          sgd-authn:
            provider: sgd-authn
            client-id: SET_ME
            client-secret: SET_ME
            scope: openid
            client-authentication-method: secret
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            #redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/oauth2/
            redirect-uri-template: "{baseUrl}/{action}/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
        provider:
          #  These are needed for talking to CAS OIDC
          sgd-authn:
            authorization-uri: ${cas.url}/oidc/authorize
            token-uri: ${cas.url}/oidc/accessToken
            jwk-set-uri: ${cas.url}/oidc/jwks
            user-info-uri: ${cas.url}/oidc/profile
            user-name-attribute: sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to get something working using option 2, adding a filter after authentication.

- Write a filter that takes in an Authentication (OAuth), runs it through some logic, and returns a new Authentication object that is instanceof a specific superclass
- Arrange for this to return isAuthenticated = false if we could not look up the OAuth2 details.
- Write a bespoke handler for NotAuthenticated

The filter is registered using something like this:

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(
            ServerHttpSecurity http,
            WebFilter proxyAuthFilter
    ) {
        return http.addFilterAt(proxyAuthFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION); // Do configuration ...
    }
```

and the filter is something like this:

```java
public class ProxyAuthFilter implements WebFilter {
    static private Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProxyAuthFilter.class);

    private final AuthZClientReactive authZClient;

    public ProxyAuthFilter(AuthZClientReactive authZClient) {
        this.authZClient = authZClient;
    }



    /**
     * Process the Web request and (optionally) delegate to the next
     * {@code WebFilter} through the given {@link WebFilterChain}.
     *
     * @param exchange the current server exchange
     * @param chain    provides a way to delegate to the next filter
     * @return {@code Mono<Void>} to indicate when request processing is complete
     */
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .flatMap(this::transform)
                .then(chain.filter(exchange));
    }

    private Mono<Authentication> transform(SecurityContext securityContext) {
        Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
        if (authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            return authenticate(authentication)
                    .map(a -> {
                        securityContext.setAuthentication(a);
                        return a;
                    });
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("ProxyFilter - not authenticated {}", authentication);
            return Mono.just(authentication);
        }
    }

    //  Runs the chain, then returns a Mono with the exchange object which completes
    //  when the auth header is added to the request.
    private Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        LOGGER.info("ProxyFilter - Checking authorisation for {}", authentication);
        Mono<AuthTokenInfo.Builder> authInfo = null;
        //  Catch if this filter runs twice
        if (authentication instanceof ProxyAuthentication) {
            LOGGER.info("ProxyAuthentication already found");
            return Mono.just(authentication);
        } else if (authentication instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) {
            //  If lookup is successful, returns instance of  ProxyAuthentication
            return getUsernamePasswordAuth((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication);
        } else if (authentication instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken) {
            //  If lookup is successful, returns instance of  ProxyAuthentication
            return getOAuthAuth((OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication);
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("Unknown principal {}", authentication);
            //  Signals a failed authentication, can be picked up by error page
            //  to display bespoke information 
            return Mono.just(new ProxyAuthenticationNotAuthenticated(
                    authentication, ProxyAuthenticationNotAuthenticated.Reason.UnknownAuthenticationType)
            );
        }
    }
```